# How to manually back up wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, backup, database-backups

I have never used wordpress before, My boss has given me access to a site which was created using wordpress. then He asked me how I am going to make sure I don't break the site accidentally, I told him I would create a backup on my local computer so that all my changes can be restored if I mess up.

I have the wordpress dashboard up. How do I back up EVERYTHING, I hear there are two separate things I need to back up? someone please help me.

**PS: I don't think he would like me to do this with out the use of additional plugins.**

Answer (score 1):

You can backup your WordPress either from your hosting account (preferable) or from your WP dashboard.

You need to backup two things - **all the files** (the root of your Wordpress installation) and the **database** for your WP installation.

Since you only have access to the dashboard, you have to use plugin for this.

Two of my favorite free backup plugins are:

- **BackupWordpress** - https://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/
- **BackWPup** - https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/

They are intuitive and easy to work with, so you shouldn't have issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate things:

- Your website database. Simply export all the MySQL tables from the database, which is dedicated to your site.
- The site files, everything you've got under WordPress folder, `/wp-includes`, `/wp-content`, `/wp-admin` directories and all files.

This should do it all. You can test on your `localhost` to make sure it's everything that's necessary.

Answer (score -2):

If you go to the dashboard go to "tools" in the left toolbar.  Select "export".  On the export page you can report that you want to export "all content".  This will get you the items that you need from the server.

Then you need to install wordpress to your machine.  You can download that from: https://wordpress.org/download/

Once you have that on your machine you also need a local server to run it and test it.  I like WAMP, but it partially depends on your operating system.  I suggest the following video to get you up to speed on how to get the localhost set up and running:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snFzbPm_RUE

Hope this helps!